How to get data validation
Usecase: I am iterating through rows in a Google sheet and taking some actions dependant on the value in different fields.
    client = authorize()
    worksheets_data = get_worksheet(client, CAREEM_SHEET, "UAE")
    sheet_data = SheetData(worksheets_data)
    rows = sheet_data.get_all_values()

    for row in rows[2:]:  # Skip header and template row
        channel_link_id = row[sheet_data.get_column_index(ActivationSheets.CAREEM_CHANNEL_LINK_ID.value)]
        careem_mapped = row[sheet_data.get_column_index(ActivationSheets.CAREEM_MAPPED.value)]
        menu_pushed = row[sheet_data.get_column_index(ActivationSheets.CAREEM_MENU_PUSHED.value)]
        created = row[sheet_data.get_column_index(ActivationSheets.CAREEM_DRECT_CREATED.value)]

        if (careem_mapped == "TRUE" and menu_pushed != "Yes" and created == "TRUE"):
            print(row)

Issue: menu_pushed is a drop down in the sheet using data validation. This does not seem to pick up any values using the  get_all_values() function.
Do you know how I can access the data validation from a cell? All I can seem to find in the docs is set_data_validation()

Example output from print statement -
['6093be05481dce29eaac6bfe', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '1/23/2022 13:45:47', '']
My SheetData class -
class SheetData:
def __init__(self, worksheet: pygsheets.Worksheet):
    self._worksheet = worksheet
    self._header_indexes = {}
    self._all_values = None
    self._populate_fields()

def _populate_fields(self):
    self._all_values = self._worksheet.get_all_values()
    headers = self._all_values[0]
    self._header_indexes = {header: index for index, header in enumerate(headers)}

@property
def header_indexes(self):
    return self._header_indexes

def get_all_values(self):
    """
    :return: all cell values from within the supplied worksheet.
    """
    return self._worksheet.get_all_values()

def authorize() -> pygsheets.client.Client:
"""
Authorizes the pygsheets client using a service account credentials file.
:param credentials_file: str location of Google Service Account credentials file.
:returns: A pygsheets.Client object.
:raises pygsheets.exceptions.PyGsheetsException: If the authorization process fails.
"""
return pygsheets.authorize(service_account_json=SPREADSHEET_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)


def get_worksheet(client: pygsheets.client.Client, spreadsheet_url: str, worksheet_name: str) -> pygsheets.Worksheet:
    """
    Fetches a worksheet from a Google Sheets spreadsheet.
    :param client: pygsheets.Client object.
    :param spreadsheet_url: str URL of the spreadsheet.
    :param worksheet_name: str name of the worksheet to retrieve.
    :returns: A pygsheets.Worksheet object representing the specified worksheet.
    :raises pygsheets.exceptions.PyGsheetsException: If the worksheet retrieval fails.
    """
    spreadsheet = client.open_by_url(spreadsheet_url)
    return spreadsheet.worksheet_by_title(worksheet_name)


About Issue: menu_pushed is a drop down in the sheet using data validation. This does not seem to pick up any values using the get_all_values() function., when I tested to retrieve the values from the data validations of the dropdown using get_all_values(). It seems that the values can be retrieved. I apologize for this situation. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating it?

Thanks for looking into this, I have added example from my sheet and also example output statement I printed.

Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation from your updated question. When I tested it, the value of "Yes" can be retrieved from the dropdown list. I apologize for this situation. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it?

Thank you, all relevant code should be there now.
Hopefully this is enough for you.

Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I cannot still find the detailed flow for correctly replicating your curent issue. But, when I tested your script using a sample Spreadsheet I prepared, unfortunately, the values of dropdown list are retrieved. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot replicate your situation soon.

Thank you @Tanaike it is now resolved.
It appears it was something inside a Google Apps Script interfering with this.
Thanks for the help!

Thank you for replying. About it is now resolved. It appears it was something inside a Google Apps Script interfering with this., I couldn't notice the issue of Google Apps Script. I apologize for my poor skill. But,  I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue is resolved, can you post it as an answer by including the detailed information? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Resolved -
This was caused by a Google Apps Script attached to this specific spreadsheet,
that was modifying the sheet and changing data validation dynamically.
Removed the unnecessary script and it worked perfectly.
